# How to implement AI for Puyo Puyo game?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

Can someone give me some pointers on how I should implement the artificial intelligence (human vs. computer gameplay) for a Puyo Puyo game? Is this project even worth pursuing?

The point of the game is to form chains of 4 or more beans of the same color that trigger other chains. The longer your chain is, the more points you get. My description isn't that great so here's a simple video of a game in progress: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1JQQbDKTd8&feature=related

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want multiple difficulties? Are you trying to design an AI that's extremely effective and super good at the game? Or just one that plays the game OK enough to convince you it knows the rules? Need more info.

Comment: Since this is mostly a learning experience, the most basic form of gameplay would be fine. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've always wanted to know how AI was done in these kinds of games. Would love to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also design a fairly simple expert system for a low-level difficulty. Something like:

```
1) Place the pieces anywhere that would result in clearing blocks
2) Otherwise, place the pieces adjacent to same-color pieces.
3) Otherwise, place the pieces anywhere.
```

This is the basic strategy a person would employ just after becoming familiar with the game. It will be passable as a computer opponent, but it's unlikely to beat anybody who has played more than 20 minutes. You also won't learn much by implementing it.

Comment: An expert system makes a lot of sense to me, and I think you could get a lot of mileage out of it if you expanded the rule-set. I think this is the approach I would take if I just going to jump in without much background research.

Answer (score 2):

Best strategy is not to kill every single chain as soon as possible, but assemble in a way, that when you brake something on top everything collapse and you get lot of combos. So problem is in assembling whit this combo strategy. It is also important that there is probably better to make 4 combos whit 5 peaces that 5 combos whit 4 peaces (but i am not sure, check whit scoring)

You should build big structure that allows this super combo moves. When building this structure you have also problem, that  you do not know, which peace you will you get (except for next peace), so there is little probability involved.

This is very **interesting problem.**

You can apply:

Dynamic programming to check the current score.
Monte Carlo for probability needs.
Little heuristics (heuristics always solve problem faster)

In general I would describe this problem as optimal positioning of peaces to maximise probability of win. There is no single strategy, because building bigger "heap" brings greater risk for loosing game.

One parameter of how good your heap is can be "entropy" - number of single/buried peaces, after making combo.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer that comes to mind is a lookahead search with [alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning). Is it worth doing? Perhaps as a learning exercise.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty standard comp sci homework problem and solution.

Comment: Alpha-Beta doesn't really apply in this case because Puyo Puyo isn't a turn based game in which a minimax strategy makes sense. You could still model the decisions you need to make as a tree and explore that tree by using a branch-and-bound strategy, but you are playing under a lot of uncertainty. You only know what pieces will be coming up one or two moves in advance. To make all this worse, each piece has four possible orientations and up to six placements. That makes your branching factor 24, pretty high.